# how to get radio button group selection

Tags: jquery

I have the following code although is there a more elegant way to getting the selected radio value as I'm already inside the code for the radio button group.  This is to get the selected radio button within a group.
Many thanks,

```
$('input[name=pig]').change(function () {

    // this seems redundant
    namespace('bla').myVariable = $('input[name=pig]:checked').val();  

    // ie. something like
    namespace('bla').myVariable = $(this).checked.val();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
namespace('bla').myVariable = this.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
  namespace('bla').myVariable = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val()` is just enough:

```
$('input[name=pig]').change(function () {
  console.log($(this).val()); // or this.value
});
```

**[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/LH72K/)**